Getting "Cluster not found/not ready. Expected node '/aliases.json' does not exist." error on Solr Cloud
We are trying to upgarde to Solr 9.6.1 and Zookeeper 3.7.1. But when connecting to Solr from Java using SolrJ Api we are getting below error.
 Cannot connect to cluster at 172.23.152.117:2181: cluster not found/not ready. Expected node '/aliases.json' does not exist.

It looks something wrong between Solr and Zookeeper.
But Solr Cluster and Zookeeper configuration looks fine.  Below is screenshot of Zookeeper status from Solr Page

Solr 9.6.1 + Zookeeper 3.7.1 combination is working. But Solr 9.6.1 + Zookeeper 3.9.2 is failing.

We found fix for the issue. 
Earlier we were configuring zookeeper host list as below 
xx.xx.xx.xx:2181

After upgrading to Zookeeper 3.7.1. we have added /solr in zookeeper host list as below. 
xx.xx.xx.xx:2181/solr

